How to measure new change in data
Suppose you have this dataframe
d = {'date':['2019-08-25', '2019-09-01', '2019-09-08'],
    'data':[31, 31, 31]}
df_sample = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df_sample.head()

and you want to measure how much new data comes in on average each week. For example, we had 31 new rows on 8/25 and then on 9/1 we got an additional 31 rows so thats like a 100% increase. What I want to know is on average from one week to the next how much new data comes in?
I know there is diff() and pct_change() but since this will just be 0 in these 3 samples I am wondering what would be the better approach here.

Can you provide the complete expected output for clarity?

If your data is cumulative, you need a cumsum before pct_change:
df_sample['change'] = df_sample['data'].cumsum().pct_change().mul(100)

Output:
         date  data  change
0  2019-08-25    31     NaN
1  2019-09-01    31   100.0
2  2019-09-08    31    50.0

Intermediate:
         date  data  cumsum  change
0  2019-08-25    31      31     NaN
1  2019-09-01    31      62   100.0
2  2019-09-08    31      93    50.0

week to week
If you want a week to week change, go with shift:
df_sample['change'] = df_sample['data'].div(df_sample['data'].shift()).mul(100)

Output:
         date  data  change
0  2019-08-25    31     NaN
1  2019-09-01    31   100.0
2  2019-09-08    31   100.0

